# Simulate keyboard interrupt to gracefully exit task in Windows?

Tags: windows, process, kill, interrupts

I have a process that doesn't behave when I do a `taskkill -f`, but the only option taskkill gives me is to kill it with -f.

When I have the exe running in the Command Prompt I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> twice and it exits gracefully with a keyboard interrupt message (it's a Python compiled exe).

How can I simulate this behavior from the command line?

Comment: I really don't know if you can, but this might guide you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540312.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541727.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff539293.aspx

Answer (score 2):

That depends from what command-line tools you have.  If you have [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html), you just activate the running program's console's window with the [`ACTIVATE` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/activate.htm) and then use the [`KEYSTACK` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/keystack.htm) to simulate that keystroke as input to the window with:

```
KEYSTACK Ctrl-C
```

Of course, if your program does not actually *have* a console when run, you do not have the option of simulating pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in its console.  ☺